# Seostats scripts

Tags: php, scripting

```
      <?php include '../src/class.seostats.php';

try 
{
        $url = new SEOstats($_GET['url']);
        $url->print_array('Google','json');

} 
catch (SEOstatsException $e) 
{
        die($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

http://code.google.com/p/seostats/

I want run this but:

```
 $url = new SEOstats($_GET['url']);
```

is error is for example **['url']** ['mywebpage.com'] or ["mywebpage.com"] error is recurrent in two versions
In first line i have 'home/myuser/public_html/class.seostats.php';
¿Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What exactly are you expecting? What are you seeing instead?

Comment: In pagerank example this is ok but in other examples not  is funtional.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of the SEOstats package and highly recommend to **not** use the reference on code.google.com. As stated on the project's start page, you should use the Github pages instead.

My 2nd recommendation is that you should use the dev branch code (which is actually stable - but not yet declared as such): https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats/tree/dev

And finally: Let me get that right: Are you trying to initialize a SEOstats instance as

`$url = new SEOstats($_GET['url']['mywebpage.com']);` ?

This is at least, what your question suggests. And if that is the case, you should better start here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php to understand the example codes of SEOstats.